# Javascript framework equivalent to Scrapy

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a framework that's equivalent to Scrapy for Javascript. I'm currently trying to build a react web app and I'm trying to find a way to scrape we pages since it doesn't provide any API. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Scraperjs](https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs), Scraperjs is a web scraper module that make scraping the web an easy job.

Scraperjs exposes two different scrapers,

a StaticScraper, that is light fast and with a low footprint, however it doesn't allow for more complex situations, like scraping dynamic content.
a DynamicScraper, that is a bit more heavy, but allows you to scrape dynamic content, like in the browser console. both scrapers expose a very similar API, with some minor differences when it comes to scraping.

**Static Scraper:**

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
scraperjs.StaticScraper.create('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
    .scrape(function($) {
        return $(".title a").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
    })
    .then(function(news) {
        console.log(news);
    })
```

**Dynamic Scraper**

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
scraperjs.DynamicScraper.create('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
    .scrape(function($) {
        return $(".title a").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
    })
    .then(function(news) {
        console.log(news);
    })
```

**or you can use [parsehub](https://www.parsehub.com/)** and play with the ParseHub API (designed around REST).

Comment: I see. Looks good. What about CasperJs? I read it somewhere that it does similar things too? How is it different from the rest?

Comment: I think ScraperJS does a great job, CaspeJS is nice too.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll try out both and see which one performs better. Thanks for your help appreciate it.